# Пробема с кодировкой

Tags: php, curl

```
$post = [
'id1' => $id1,
'id2' => $id2,
'id3' => $is3,
];

$post = http_build_query($postData);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

После http_build_query, я получаю что то на подобии этого (%D2%E5%F1%F2%EE%E2%EE%E5+%F1%EE%EE%E1%F9%E5%ED%E8%E5+%E2+%EB%E8%F7%), a не значение (на русском) исправить не получается

Comment: Именно так и должно быть, всё в порядке

Comment: Вопрос в том что мне нужно вернуть значения на русском, чтобы принимающий сервер мог ее нормально записать.

Comment: Здесь url-закодирован русский текст «Тестовое сообщение в лич» в кодировке CP1251. Если сервер принимает именно CP1251, то всё в полном порядке. Но, возможно, он принимает другую кодировку, и ваша исходная русская строка, возможно, должна быть, например, в кодировке UTF-8. Но к в вот этим вот процентикам это не имеет никакого отношения — они **должны** быть, здесь всё в порядке. Разбирайтесь с кодировкой исходний русской строки

Comment: приложение windows-1251 принимающий сервис utf-8

Comment: Ну вот переводите ваше приложение на utf-8

Comment: я перевел массив в строку, iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $post)

Comment: А нужно переводить не массив, а строки в массиве

Comment: Вроде и так сработало, все отправило

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно, потому что http_build_query приводит русский текст к виду который поддерживается при отправке http, так даже все браузеры делают (только некоторые скрывают это). 
Тоесть проще говоря - сервер на который вы отправляете запрос получит нормальный русский текст.
Если же вы хотитедекодировать эту строку, то в php есть такая функция как urldecode, которая преобразует закодированый текст в нормальную строку, вот здесь продробнее:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php